Chained conditional relationship
I have a view which lists hundreds of people based on a category. I need to add a custom order for each individual category to highlight some of the people, so I created a taxonomy. Each taxonomy term has 3 fields:

Person's name
Category name
Weight

I've added the taxonomy as a relationship for the view, and added the weight as a sort, this works great, but it is universal across all categories. When I try to add a category term as another relationship field it either removes everyone without a taxonomy term or does nothing.
So what I essentially have is the equivalent of (I've cut the category join out for ease):
SELECT * FROM people LEFT JOIN weights ON weights.persons_name = people.name WHERE people.category = 'example' ORDER BY weights.weight
But what I need is:
SELECT * FROM people LEFT JOIN weights ON weights.persons_name = people.name AND weights.category_name = category.name WHERE people.category = 'example' ORDER BY weights.weight
I'm completely stumped, on 2 occasions I've had to restore from a backup even.

Why do you have "Person's name" as field of taxonomy term? Is each of your term associated to some particular person's name? Just asking, if the question is posted correctly, because it is quite unusual design of fields.

First off thanks for taking a look. The system is a legacy that I've inherited. The view already exists which I am trying to modify - otherwise I would have done it from genre down. I don't think using name/id really affects the issue with the left join needing an AND clause though.
The taxonomy field using person's name is actually person's ID in reality.
